# A question about Fisher–Neyman factorization theorem

Tags: statistics, self-learning, statistical-inference

$f_{\theta}(x)$, then $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$ if and only if nonnegative functions $g$ and $h$ can be found such that

$f_{\theta} = h(x)g_{\theta}(T(x)) $

The statement is:  if $F(t)$ is a one to one function and $T$ is a sufficient statistic, then $F(T)$ is a sufficient statistic.

I can't see this from the factorization criterion, how is  $F(T)$ a sufficient statistic?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite clear that if $F$ is one-to-one, then an inverse $F^{-1}$ exists and is also one-to-one, thus if we are given $F(T)$ we can recover $T$ through inversion, and since $T$ is sufficient, $F(T)$ is as well.

For instance, if I know that the sum of the observations in the sample is sufficient for a parameter $\theta$, then I also know that twice the sum is also sufficient.  I also know that the sample mean is sufficient.  The square of the sum is **not necessarily** sufficient.  It could be if the support of the distribution from which the observations were drawn is nonnegative, because then the transformation is one-to-one on the support; but if the support is, say, $(-\infty, \infty)$, then no, such a transformation is not one-to-one on this interval and therefore will not result in a sufficient statistic.

Comment: I was thinking maybe one can show it by utilizing  the factorization criterion , @heropup how did you use the factorization criterion ?

Comment: It is fairly simple; if $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$, then $$g_\theta^*(y) = g_\theta(F^{-1}(y))$$ gives you $$g_\theta^*(F(T(\boldsymbol x))) = g_\theta(T(\boldsymbol x)),$$ and so $g^*$ is your function of the sufficient statistic $F(T)$.